# Python installable package

Tags: python, cmd, pip, package

So I am doing a project where I have to create an installable Python package, install it on my desktop (Windows OS) and run the application contained in the folder. After packing and installing the code, I get 2 folders in the path where pip is installed:

```
project_pkg
project_pkg-0.0.1.dist-info
```

In the project_pkg folder I have 1 folder and 2 files:

```
__pycache__
__init__.py
project.py
```

What I want to do is run project.py via the cmd. How can I do it? The file **init**.py contains only this:

```
name = 'project'
```

**UPDATE**

After reading @Patrick Allen answer I figured out everything.Now I can run the application just by typing `project [args]`. When I do it the up runs as expected and the output is correct, but when it's about to finish, I get this weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python37 
-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\project.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The thing is that I am not using a `__main__.py`, plus when I try to look for the file specified by the last path, I cant find anything. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

I figured a temporary solution, that uses the command `sys.exit()` when the application is done running. I dont know if it correct, but works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `setup.py` packaging, you will need to set the `entry_points` configuration.

Check out Kenneth Reitz' example repo. He has it commented out, but just uncomment it and transform it to apply to your project.

[Packaging Example Repo](https://github.com/kennethreitz/setup.py/blob/master/setup.py#L109)

Provided you are working within the python environment you installed your project in, this will allow you to just type `project [args]` into your command line.

Here is the documentation on python packaging: [Python Packaging Docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Example:

Let's say that you have a project with the following structure:

```
project
  project/
    __init__.py
    cli.py
  setup.py
  README.md
  LICENSE
```

With a function named `main` in `cli.py` that is responsible for the execution of the code.

You would change the commented out code in Kenneth's repo to be:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['project=project.cli:main'],
},
```

Comment: @C.Nivs solution worked for me, but I will try this out too. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Cool. Either one works fine. Just note that @C.Nivs solution, while valid, does not create an installable python package.

Comment: Hmmm it does not run by just project [args]... All I did was add the commented out code in my setup.py file. But when I run project [args] in the cmd I get

'project' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any Ideas @Patrick Allen?

Comment: Nop, just found the answer. I have to give the cmd command my own name instead of 'mycli'.

Comment: Yup, glad you found it.. I'll update to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Run modules with cmd using the `-m` flag:

```
python -m <package-name>
```

In your case

```
python -m project
```